# Why can't I trigger form submit event in next.js page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a very simple login form in pages/login. However, when I try to submit it, the submit event never seems to be called, and the default event does not get prevented.

```
const login = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        onSubmit={async e => {
          // never called
          debugger;
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        Don't have an account?
        <Link href="/signup">
          <a>Sign up here</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default login;
```

I expect the debugger to be hit, and the default event to be prevented, but neither happend. I have done similar things in React many times, but I am relatively new to next.js, so I assume this must be due to some behavior of next that I am not understanding. Any help appreciated!

Edit* Ok, I found what is causing the bug. On the server, I am using jwt auth, so I havethis code to prevent an unauthenticated user from viewing any pages.

../server/app.js (main server module)

```
server.use(
      jwt({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
      }).unless({ path: ["/login", "/signup", "/graphql"] })
    );

    server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      if (err.name === "UnauthorizedError") {
        return res.redirect("/login");
      }
      next();
    });
```

When I comment out that block of code, the form on  the client is processed as normal. Not sure why that has an effect, but in any case, I need that code, so I would love to know why it is causing a problem!

Answer (score 2):

It is because you add listener `onSubmit` on your form, but there is no submit event there.
It is related to your html component, instead of using next/link and tag a, you should use ***submit button to trigger `onSubmit` event***.

And since you are using onSubmit event, you need to remove Link component and replace it with Router component from NextJS which will be called inside your `onSubmit` function.

```js
import Router from "next/router";

const login = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        onSubmit={async e => {
          // never called
          debugger;
          e.preventDefault();
          Router.push("/signup");
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        Don't have an account?
        <button type="submit">Sign up here</button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default login;
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't support using events asynchronously without extra steps. It doesn't look like you need this, so just change `onSubmit={async e => {` to `onSubmit={e => {`.

Comment: Thanks. Doesnt seem to have worked though. Took out the async keyword but I still get the same behavior

Comment: Then there's a problem in part of your code that you didn't show. When I test the exact component you posted with just that one change, it works for me.

Comment: Hmm very strange. No other code in this file. I extended the app with a higher order component so I could use apollo client. Any reason that would affect it? I can post the code if you want but its alot.

Comment: I edited the post to show the cause of the bug. Would love to know how I can fix that block of code so it doesnt cause an issue though, since I would like to be able to protect my routes!